# Como responder con un status = 200 a un HTTPS POST en python

Tags: python, https, flask

Estoy creando una aplicación en Flask que recibe un mensaje HTTPS POST y procesa los datos que contiene.

Una vez he recibido el mensaje HTTPS, tengo que contestar al servidor con un code = 200 para que sepa que he recibido el mensaje y no me lo reenvie a los pocos segundos. El problema que tengo es que se ejecuta más codigo antes de llegar al return y da tiempo a recibir 2 o 3 mensajes del servidor antes de llegar al return.

¿Como puedo mandar el code 200 en mitad del codigo y recibir realmente solo un mensaje? ¿Tengo que hacer un HTTPS GET a pesar de que no pido nada?

```
 app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])``
def webhook():
req = request.form
xml = req['data']
#HOW DO I SEND A CODE 200 NOW???
info = ET.fromstring(xml)
print info[0].text
print info[1].text
print info[2].text
print info[3].text
sender = email()
return None
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En estos casos lo que se hace generalmente es mover la parte pesada a un hilo/proceso de forma que la petición en sí pueda emitir la respuesta de forma 'inmediata'. Claro está, esto solo es posible si la respuesta no va a contener el resultado de lo que queremos procesar, como en este caso. Lo mas simple es algo como:

```
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

def procesar(xml):
    info = ET.fromstring(xml)
    print info[0].text
    print info[1].text
    print info[2].text
    print info[3].text
    sender = email()


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])``
def webhook():
    req = request.form
    xml = req['data']
    t = Thread(target=procesar, args=(xml,))
    t.start()
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, debug=debug, threaded=True)
```

Esto es solo a modo de ejemplo, asegurate que de que aquello que manejes en los hilos sea thread-safe.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta :)!!! La verdad es que nunca he trabajado con multi - hilos... ¿Entiendo entonces que todo lo que haga en un hilo no se va a quedar guardado para usarlo más adelante?¿Si yo hago un HTTPS GET en el hilo conservo la respuesta para usarla luego?

Comment: @Alex la idea de lo que expongo arriba es pasar los datos a procesar al hilo. Puedes compartir datos entre hilos de forma segura, por ejemplo mediante el uso de colas ([queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)). Todo depende de lo  que quieras hacer en realidad, hay muchas formas de implementar tareas asíncronas desde procesos, hilos, celery, twisted, etc pero depende de lo que quieras hacer. Si solo vas a procesar los datos usa hilos o procesos y comparte el resultado con el hilo pricnipal usando colas.Tambien podrias usar piscinas de procesos como multiprocessing.pool. Saludos

Comment: Genial! La cosa es que abriré un hilo nuevo donde se siguen procesando cosas y el codigo llegará al "return None" y finalizará ese hilo ¿no? (Logicamente antes de que acabe el nuevo hilo en el que se hacen bastantes cosas)

Comment: @Alex el hilo seguirá haciendo su trabajo hasta que termine lo que tenga que hacer, la función que lo lanza (en este caso `webhook`) terminará por un lado y el hilo por otro. Esto permite que la función retorne enviando la respuesta 200 al server, el hilo mientras tanto seguirá procesando los datos aunque la función ya terminó.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la ayuda :) ¿Hay alguna forma de puntuarte positivamente o algo por la ayuda? jajaja

Comment: @Alex en [es.so] hay dos formas de valorar las respuestas, votando positivo/negatico y aceptandolas. Para aceptar una respuesta mirate el procedimiento en este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas. Votar no puedes aún por falta de reputación pero si puedes aceptar respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Y, la última, el hilo tengo que cerrarlo con un "return None" también?

Comment: @Alex no tienes porqué, ten en cuenta que las funciones en Python retornan todas  `None ` a no ser que especifiques lo contrario tu (con  `return` o  `yield `). De hecho,  `return None ` es prescindible, si no se usa la función retorna  `None ` por defecto de todas forma aunque no exista ningún return. Saludos.